# Extraer valores de un array cuando sean igual a X1

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un array con algunos valores, pero sólo tengo que extraer y mostrar los valores que son iguales a X1, estos valores los traigo de mi base de datos.

```
array
  0 => string 'X1' (length=2)
  1 => string 'X1' (length=2)
  2 => string 'X1' (length=2)
  3 => string 'X1' (length=2)
  4 => string 'SE' (length=2)
  5 => string 'SO' (length=2)
```

Esta es el array de la que debo extraer sólo los valores X1

y con Forech estoy tratando de pasar y extraer los valores de XI de esta matriz, pero no funcionaría

```
foreach($codigo_movimiento as $cantidad_codigo_movimiento){
    if ($cantidad_codigo_movimiento == 'X1') {
        
        var_dump($cantidad_codigo_movimiento);
    }
}
```

Aclaro que estos valores los estoy consumiendo desde un servicio y no directamente desde una base de datos propia.

Comment: Al hacer el var_dump, que te arroja ¿?

Comment: @Excorpion al hacer var_dump no me devuelve nada, solo una pantalla en blanco

Comment: Entonces lo más probable es que haya problemas al rescatar el array, y asignarlo a $codigo_movimiento. Esa parte del código no la estamos viendo, y no sabemos como estás rescatando y asignando ese array.

Comment: Probé tu código acá y funciona: https://paiza.io/projects/Gm0cvxPGAfbYjlv9OYmMYg de igual manera te agregué otra forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función filter:

> array_filter: Recorre cada valor de array, pasándolos a la función callback. Si la función callback devuelve TRUE el valor actual desde array es devuelto al array resultante. Las claves del array se conservan.

[Filter php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

En tu caso si el array se llama `$codigo_movimiento` puedes indicar:

```php
$codigo_movimiento =  ["X1","X3","X1"];
$filtrado = array_filter($codigo_movimiento, function($item){ return $item == "X1"; });
var_dump($filtrado);
```

Se utiliza la función array_filter, se le pasa en el primer parámetro el arreglo a filtrar, el segundo parámetro es una función (llamada callback) que indicará por cada elemento si debe ser tomado o no retornando un true o falto dependiendo de la condición indicada.

En este caso $item en la función será en algún momento "X1" luego "X3" y luego "X1", entonces cada vez que la función callback retorne true ese elemento será enviado al nuevo array que queda almacenado en `$filtrado`.

Saludos!.